# Calculate Group Mean and Overall Mean

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with several variables I want to get the means of and a variable I want to group by.  Then, I would like to get the proportion of each group's mean to the overall mean.

I have put together the following, but it is clumsy.

How would you go about it using `dplyr` or `data.table`?  Bonus points for the option to return both the intermediate step (group and overall mean) and the final proportions.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  X1 = sample(1:10),
  X2 = sample(11:20),
  X3 = sample(21:30),
  Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

groupMeans <- Data %>% 
  group_by(Y) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(mean))

overallMeans <- Data %>% 
  select(-Y) %>% 
  summarize_all(funs(mean))

index <- sweep(as.matrix(groupMeans[, -1]), MARGIN = 2,  as.matrix(overallMeans), FUN = "/")
```

Comment: The library `dplyr` is a part of `tidyverse` package, so you have is all ready using dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one more dplyr solution

```
index <- as.data.frame(Data %>% 
    group_by(Y) %>%
    summarise_all(mean) %>%
    select(-Y)  %>%
    rbind(Data %>% select(-Y) %>% summarise_all(mean))%>%
    mutate_all(funs( . / .[3])))[1:2,]
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works great.  Just to understand the `mutate_all` bit.  It divides every element by the third element?  What can I use to replace this [3] with a dynamic number based on the number of columns of data?

Comment: Yes, you can use not figure, which indicates number of column but variable to which you can assign different values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible `dplyr` solution that contains everything you want:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Y) %>%
  summarise(
    group_avg_X1 = mean(X1),
    group_avg_X2 = mean(X2),
    group_avg_X3 = mean(X3)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    overall_avg_X1 = mean(group_avg_X1),
    overall_avg_X2 = mean(group_avg_X2),
    overall_avg_X3 = mean(group_avg_X3),
    proportion_X1 = group_avg_X1 / overall_avg_X1,
    proportion_X2 = group_avg_X2 / overall_avg_X2,
    proportion_X3 = group_avg_X3 / overall_avg_X3
  )

# # A tibble: 2 x 10
#   Y     group_avg_X1 group_avg_X2 group_avg_X3 overall_avg_X1 overall_avg_X2 overall_avg_X3 proportion_X1
#   <fct>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 no             6.6         14.6         25.8            5.5           15.5           25.5           1.2
# 2 yes            4.4         16.4         25.2            5.5           15.5           25.5           0.8
# # ... with 2 more variables: proportion_X2 <dbl>, proportion_X3 <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method with `data.table`:

```
#data
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(
  x1 = sample(1:10),
  x2 = sample(11:20),
  x3 = sample(21:30),
  y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

# group means
group_means <- dt[ , lapply(.SD, mean), by=y, .SDcols=1:3]

# overall means
overall_means <- dt[ , lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols=1:3]

# clunky combination (sorry!)
group_means[ , perc_x1 := x1 / overall_means[[1]] ]
group_means[ , perc_x2 := x2 / overall_means[[2]] ]
group_means[ , perc_x3 := x3 / overall_means[[3]] ]
```