# Idiomatic dplyr and/or data.table way to get group means and grand means "idiomatically" in a single step

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I use both `dplyr` and `data.table` so I am interested if there is a solution using either package.

I commonly want to summarize data with summary statistics -- let's say mean for the sake of example -- both by some grouping variable and across the entire dataset (grand mean). Then I typically combine them into a single output dataframe for display, with the grand mean row designated "total" or "overall" in the grouping variable column.

Here is how I usually do that, using both `dplyr` and `data.table`:

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(grp = rep(letters[1:3], 10), v = 1:30)

group_means <- d %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(v_mean = mean(v))
grand_means <- d %>%
  summarize(v_mean = mean(v)) %>%
  mutate(grp = 'overall')

bind_rows(group_means, grand_means)
```

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)

d <- data.table(grp = rep(letters[1:3], 10), v = 1:30)

group_means <- d[, .(v_mean = mean(v)), by = .(grp)]
grand_means <- d[, .(v_mean = mean(v))]
grand_means[, grp := 'overall']

rbindlist(list(group_means, grand_means), use.names = TRUE)
```

My issue is that this isn't very concise. It's not that bad in this example, but if I have to calculate a large number of summary statistics, I have to repeat the same code twice. My question is, **is there an idiomatic and concise way to get both grouped and overall summary statistics in either dplyr or data.table**?

Comment: Maybe refactor to create own summary function like https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html ?

Comment: @danlooo Yes, I was considering adding a function for this into my own personal R package but I often share code with clients and it's sometimes inconvenient to share my own custom functions with them. Thus my preference for finding an existing solution :-)

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51793662/680068

Comment: take a look at the data.table's groupingsets functions, like cube(). See also my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed my previous answer as I found this neat data.table function

```
data.table::cube(d, mean(v), by = c("grp"))
```

This gives you (sub)totals of your groups

```
    grp   V1
1:    a 14.5
2:    b 15.5
3:    c 16.5
4: <NA> 15.5
```

Including replacing `NA` and the correct column name

```
data.table::cube(d, .(v_mean = mean(v)), by = c("grp"))[is.na(grp), grp := "overall"][]

       grp v_mean
1:       a   14.5
2:       b   15.5
3:       c   16.5
4: overall   15.5
```

More info can be found here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/groupingsets

Answer (score 4):

Here's a concise way with **dplyr**:

```
d %>%
  add_row(grp = 'overall', v = mean(.$v)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(mean_v = mean(v))
```

Another option, to avoid repeating summary stats calculation twice:

```
d %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(., grp = 'overall')) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(mean_v = mean(v))
```

Comment: This is great but still repeats the calculation of summary stats twice, which could still become unwieldy if that calculation is long and involved.

Comment: @qdread You could also bind the entire table back to itself (with grp renamed) and calculate all stats in the final step (see update)