Aggregate of a table along with Total at the bottom; using data.table package
This is a sample data.
library(data.table);
DTmtcars<-as.data.table(mtcars,keep.rownames = TRUE);

I need this summary table, however I also need a total row.
DTmtcars[, .(
QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
VS =  sum(vs !=0)),  
by = gear]

total row should have these values:
DTmtcars[, .(
QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
VS =  sum(vs !=0))]


Maybe just add rbindlist to your approach.

That’s something I don’t want to do because in my data this aggregate table is quite big and many. I don’t want 2 of each. There must be some functionality.

I asked a similar question in the past and got some good answers, in particular check out the data.table::cube() function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705047/idiomatic-dplyr-and-or-data-table-way-to-get-group-means-and-grand-means-idioma

Also see https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/03/creating-blazing-fast-pivot-tables-from-r-with-data-table-now-with-subtotals-using-grouping-sets/

cube(DTmtcars,
     .(QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
     DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
     VS =  sum(vs !=0)),  
by = "gear")

Output
    gear     QSEC     DISP    VS
   <num>    <num>    <num> <int>
1:     4 18.96500 123.0167    10
2:     3 17.69200 326.3000     3
3:     5 15.64000 202.4800     1
4:    NA 17.84875 230.7219    14

required output:
> DTmtcars[, .(
+   QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
+   DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
+   VS =  sum(vs !=0))]
       QSEC     DISP    VS
      <num>    <num> <int>
1: 17.84875 230.7219    14


Use data.table::rbind with fill:
rbind(
  DTmtcars[, .(
    QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
    DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
    VS =  sum(vs !=0)),  
    by = gear],
  DTmtcars[, .(
    QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
    DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
    VS =  sum(vs !=0))], 
  fill = TRUE)

Or loop with ifelse and use rbindlist:
rbindlist(
  lapply(1:2, function(i){
    if(i == 1){
      DTmtcars[, .(
        QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
        DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
        VS =  sum(vs !=0)),  
        by = gear]
    } else {
      DTmtcars[, .(
        QSEC = mean(qsec) ,
        DISP = sum(disp)/.N ,
        VS =  sum(vs !=0))]
    }
  }), fill = TRUE)

#    gear     QSEC     DISP    VS
#   <num>    <num>    <num> <int>
#1:     4 18.96500 123.0167    10
#2:     3 17.69200 326.3000     3
#3:     5 15.64000 202.4800     1
#4:    NA 17.84875 230.7219    14

